# Django i18n: Specifying context. (msgctxt)

Tags: django, internationalization

This page, about gettext generally, mentions the ability to specify a context for a string marked for translation. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files)  This helps when you have two instances of the same string in an application that have different meanings (e.g. "back" in one instance may mean "go back" while in another it may mean "not the front" -- it's possible that these are two different words in a foreign language)

Does Django's i18n allow you to specify a context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes since version 1.3 Django supports "Contextual Markers". See eg. this example from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers):

```
 from django.utils.translation import pgettext

 month = pgettext("month name", "May")
```

Comment: Is there a similar facility for use in templates?

Comment: No for templating you just find the `trans` and `blocktrans` (which at least enables you to use pluralization) tags...